# count(*) in dbms_sql.number_table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have declared a number table like:

```
v_areas_hijas   dbms_sql.number_table;
```

I fill the table and then I'm trying to get the size of that table with:

```
select count(*) into v_counter from v_areas_hijas;
```

but I'm getting:

> Error(23,37): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

How should I get that size?

Comment: `v_areas_hijas` is a local collection variable (specifically it's an associative array), not a relational table you can use in SQL (not just `count(*)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the `count` method of the collection works.

```
declare
    p_ids dbms_sql.number_table;
    cnt NUMBER;
begin
    p_ids(1) := 2;
    p_ids(2) := 3;
    p_ids(3) := 4;
    dbms_output.put_line('cnt '||p_ids.count);
end;
/
```

returns

```
 cnt 3
```

Comment: Relevant docs: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/collections.htm#CJAEIFCA

Comment: So was it getting the total number of elements in a collection variable that you wanted, or the ability to run SQL queries in general? e.g. the number of values starting with `A`.

Answer (score 0):

`v_areas_hijas` is a local collection variable (specifically it's an associative array), not a relational table you can use in SQL (not just `count(*)`). You can cast some collections to relational tables using the `table()` operator, although there are limitations with scope and compatibility depending on the type, where it's declared and which version of Oracle you have (11g, 12c R1 and 12c R2 have different capabilities.)

Using a globally declared SQL collection type created with `create or replace type` (or an existing one like `sys.ku$_xmlcolset_t`) you can do something like this:

```
declare 
    v_areas_hijas sys.ku$_xmlcolset_t := sys.ku$_xmlcolset_t(1,10,100);
    v_counter integer;
begin
    select count(*) into v_counter from table(v_areas_hijas);
    dbms_output.put_line('Count = ' || v_counter);
end;
```