# dbms_sql.number_table in IN statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have declared a number table like:

```
v_areas_hijas   dbms_sql.number_table;
```

I fill the table and then I'm trying this comparation:

```
  select 
  idarea
from areas 
where 
  IDAREAPADRE in v_areas_hijas;
```

but I'm getting:

> Error(45,22): PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type

How should I do that IN statement?

**EDIT 1: using "member of"**

```
  select 
      idarea
    from areas 
    where 
      IDAREAPADRE member of v_areas_hijas;
```

I've got this two errors:

> Error(45,29): PLS-00382:expression is of wrong type
>
> Error(45,29): PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes expected UDT got CHAR

in the table *AREAS*, *IDAREA* and *IDAREAPADRE* are ***NUMBER***,

Comment: What's the type of v_areas_hijas_tmp?

Comment: @kfinity same as v_areas_hijas:  dbms_sql.number_table;

Answer (score 0):

As in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48668427/count-in-dbms-sql-number-table), `v_areas_hijas` is not a table. If it's a collection type defined in SQL you can use the `member of` collection operator:

```
select idarea bulk collect into v_areas_hijas_tmp 
from   areas 
where  idareapadre member of v_areas_hijas;
```

For example, using the predefined type `sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll` (look in`all_coll_types` for more examples),

```
declare 
    t_demo sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll := sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('X','Y','Z');
    l_result integer;
begin
    select count(*) into l_result
    from   dual
    where  dummy member of t_demo;

    -- Or this:
    select count(*) into l_result
    from   dual
    where  dummy in
           ( select column_value from table(t_demo) );

    -- Or this:
    select count(*) into l_result
    from   dual d
           join table(t_demo) t on t.column_value = d.dummy;

    dbms_output.put_line(l_result);
end;
```

You can use the `table()` operator on nested table and varray types declared in packages:

```
create or replace package demo
as
    type demo_collection_type is table of varchar2(1);
end demo;
```

then

```
declare 
    t_demo demo.demo_collection_type := demo.demo_collection_type('X','Y','Z');
    l_result integer;
begin
    select count(*) into l_result
    from   dual
    where  dummy in
           ( select column_value from table(t_demo) t );

    dbms_output.put_line(l_result);

    -- Or:
    select count(*) into l_result
    from   dual d
           join table(t_demo) t on t.column_value = d.dummy;

    dbms_output.put_line(l_result);
end;
```

As of 12.1 you can't use `member of` for collection types declared in PL/SQL packages.

Some of these restrictions are lifted in 12.2.

Comment: mmm nop same PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type

Comment: What's the type of `idareapadre`? Is it a number?

Comment: yes it's a number too, but: Error(45,29): PL/SQL: ORA-00932: tipos de dato inconsistentes: se esperaba UDT se ha obtenido CHAR

Comment: Well it works if you use the right type. I would have to know more details to get it working in your example which you forgot to share.

Comment: I think the problem is that `v_areas_hijas_tmp` is not a TABLE OF whatever `idarea` is. Please show us your entire code.

Comment: I still don't see the definition of `v_areas_hijas_tmp`.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson let me remove that variable it's not relevante and without it it's the same error

Comment: Okay, it looks like the UDT error is because `dbms_sql.number_table` is a "User Defined Type" - it's part of a package - so it doesn't work the same way as regular collections. If you create your own SQL type (or use a predefined one like dbms_debug_vc2coll) this code will work fine.

Comment: Updated answer.